# How to make vim understand env variable between parenthesis'()' in makefile?

Tags: vim, makefile

I am trying to use `gf` on a file path with parenthesis like below

```
$(env_var)/aaa/bbb/foo.txt
```

Even though I set `isfname` but it seems Vim takes it as a whitespace
`set isfname -=(,)`

When I used `isfname` like below, it seems parentheses are read by Vim but it doesn't work
`set isfname +=(,)`

Is there any way to use `gf` with env var inside of parenthesis?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do more sophisticated substitutions on `gf`, you can use `includeexpr`. It provides a fallback for `gf` as documented in `:help gf`.

First, you need to add parentheses to `isfname` as you have already done to capture `$(env_var)`

Then you can write a tiny, substituting function.

To use it only on makefiles, you should put the following code in `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/make.vim`:

```vim
setlocal isfname+=(,)
setlocal includeexpr=substitute(v:fname,'\\$(\\(.\\{-}\\))','\\=getenv(submatch(1))','g')
```

This will look through the file name below the cursor and replace the string `$(env_var)` with the result of `getenv(env_var)`. The regular expression looks a bit intimidating because backslashes have to be escaped twice. It is roughly equivalent to `$(.*)` and captures anything inside the parentheses non-greedily as a submatch. That submatch is then fed into `getenv()`.

See [`:help 'includeexpr'`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27includeexpr%27) and [`:help substitute()`](https://vimhelp.org/builtin.txt.html#substitute%28%29) for reference.

Keep in mind that `env_var` may have a completely different value when you're editing and when you're running your file.

A more orthodox alternative would be to add wherever `env_var` points to to the `path` option.

Comment: using `\v` can help with backslash madness

Comment: @balki thanks for your comment. I didn't consider using `\v`. As it turns out, the corresponding *very magic* regexp is `\\v\\$\\((.{-})\\)` which features 8 backslashes as well. So, unfortunately, there's nothing to be gained.

Comment: yeah in this case not much difference. `\\v[$][(]([^)]*).` avoids some backslashes but very readable.